# QML - event.modifiers doesn't work when using Menu QML type

Tags: qt, events, qml

in QML when I used Menu QML type, event.modifiers didn't work in Keys.onPressed,  but after commenting Menu type it worked. What am I doing wrong? is there any bug related to Menu QML type?
I am using Qt 5.4.0.

```
Rectangle {
id: main
width: 600
height: 300

Menu {
    id: menu
    title: "Edit";

    MenuItem { text: "Copy";shortcut: "Ctrl+C" }
    MenuItem { text: "Paste";shortcut: "Ctrl+V" }
    MenuItem { text: "Select" }
    MenuItem { text: "Select all";shortcut: "Ctrl+A" }

    MenuSeparator { }
    MenuItem { text: "Delete";shortcut: "Delete" }
    MenuItem { text: "Delete all" }

    MenuSeparator { }
    MenuItem { text: "Auto arrange" }

    }

Keys.onPressed: {
    if((event.key === Qt.Key_C) && (event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier))
    {
        console.log("Ctrl+C is pressed")
    }
}

MouseArea{
    anchors.fill : parent;
    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

    onClicked: {
        main.focus = true;
        if(mouse.button === Qt.RightButton){
            menu.popup();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Menu` is not a [visual primitive](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html#details) (`QQuickItem`), and hence doesn't receive events:

> All visual primitives support key handling via the Keys attached property.

The `shortcut` property that you're currently using is the correct way to provide shortcuts to menus. You can also assign an [`action`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menuitem.html#action-prop).

To respond to a shortcut being triggered, use the [`triggered`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menuitem.html#triggered-signal) signal.